# How do i center text and an image with flexbox properly?

Tags: html, css

I tried to center "Travel Blog;View Project" with the image, so the text is in the middle of the image on the left side. Not overlapping

I tried using flexbox grid, but i dont have any clue what to do now

the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fabian Gmeindl</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="showcase">
      <div class="Top-Page">

      <h1>HEY,</h1>
      <h2>I'm Fabian Gmeindl</h2>
      <p>Skier, Writer, Entrepreneur</p>

      </div>
    </header>
      <div id="project-home">



      <!-- Top Page -->

      <!-- Page Projects -->
      <div class="rtro-area" class="wrapper">




        <h2>Travel Blog</h2>
        <a href="https://www.rtrobrand.com">View Project</a>
        </div>
        <img  class="img-rtro" class="wrapper" src="Resources/rtro-toppage.png" alt="Rtro Blog Top Page">


        <footer id="main footer">
          <p>Copyright &copy; 2019 Fabian Gmeindl</p>
        </footer>

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the css

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border:0;

}


h1{
  color:#56A1B1;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;

}

#showcase h2{
  color:white;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p{
  color:white;
}

.Top-Page{
  padding-left: 8%;
}
body{
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  line-height: 1;

}


#showcase{
  background-image: url('../Resources/Portrait.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}



/* Project Home Page */




.img-rtro{
  width: 1300px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20%;

}

#project-home{
background-image: url('../Resources/background.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
}
```

When I scroll down to the second section, where the problem is, it looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxaie.jpg

Comment: can you give us working example of it with images

Comment: Canter it with which image?

Answer (score 0):

You can align the "Travel Blog;View Project" part if you add *align-items: center* to the flexcontainer's CSS. (*align-items* — controls alignment of all items on the cross axis.) You have to center on the cross axis, as you are using "flex-direction: column".

For aligning elements with flexbox in general, I can recommend this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container